# In node.js, why is my Promise.all not seeing my array of promises created by my prior for loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, promise

My goal is to loop through an array of objects and add them to a MongoDB database if that object doesn't already exist inside the database. I want my code to wait until all of the objects have been added before moving on, so I have added a Promise.all function and add any insertOne functions into an array of promises called 'promises'.

```
//Loop through currentActiveMarkets, add any insertOne requests to promises array
var promises = [];
for (let market of currentActiveMarkets){
    console.log("   Looking to see if marketHash exists: " + market.marketHash)
    //Search if marketHash already exists in MongoDB
    dbo.collection("bettingmarkets").findOne({ marketHash: market.marketHash }, function(err, exists) { 
        if (err) throw err;
        //if currentActiveMarkets is found in MongoDB already, do nothing
        if (exists) {
            console.log("   marketHash " + market.marketHash + " exists") 
        //if currentActiveMarkets is not found in MongoDB, insert it by adding to promise list
        } else { 
            console.log("   marketHash doesn't exist")
            var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, refuse){
                dbo.collection("bettingmarkets").insertOne(market, function(err, res) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log("   marketHash added to MongoDB: " + market.marketHash);
                    return resolve;
                })
            })
            //logging confirms promises are being added to promises array
            console.log("promise: " + promise);
            promises.push(promise);
            console.log("promises: " + promises);
        };
    });
};
Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
    console.log("   All non-duplicate ActiveMarkets have been added to MongoDB.");
    console.log(promises)// why are no promises making it into this Promise All array????
    })
    .catch((e) => {
        console.log("   Error with Promise All: " + e);
    });
```

The problem is that Promise.all appears to be executing before anything is run inside the for loop. Logs shows an empty promises array == [] when Promise.all is run.

Inside the actual for loop, the logs show that my promise objects are being added to the promises array each time insertOne is called, but like I said, Promise.all isn't seeing them in the array. Promise.all is being executed before the promises are added to the promises array.

How can I change my code so that Promise.all(promises) isn't executed until the for loop is complete and the promises have been added to the promises array?

Comment: Your promises are never resolved. Change `return resolve` to `resolve()`

Comment: Because the promises are still being added to the array asynchronously and aren't there when the `Promise.all` gets called.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your promises array isn't getting populated in time because you try to populate it from an asynchronous callback.

```js
const timeout = delay => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, delay));
const dummy = word => timeout(1000).then(() => word);

{
  const promises = [];
  timeout(1000).then(() => {
    // Too late!
    promises.push(dummy("hello"));
  });
  Promise.all(promises).then(p => {
    console.log(`First: ${p}`);
  });
}

{
  const promises = [];
  // On time
  promises.push(
    timeout(1000).then(() => dummy("hello"))
  );
  Promise.all(promises).then(p => {
    console.log(`Second: ${p}`);
  });
}
```

The Mongo driver supports async/await.  Try writing it like this:

```
const promises = currentActiveMarkets.map(async market => {
    console.log("   Looking to see if marketHash exists: " + market.marketHash)

    const bettingMarkets = dbo.collection("bettingmarkets")

    //Search if marketHash already exists in MongoDB
    const exists = await bettingMarkets.findOne({ marketHash: market.marketHash });

    //if currentActiveMarkets is found in MongoDB already, do nothing
    if (exists) {
        console.log("   marketHash " + market.marketHash + " exists") 
        return;
    }

   //if currentActiveMarkets is not found in MongoDB, insert it by adding to promise list
   console.log("   marketHash doesn't exist")

   const res = await bettingMarkets.insertOne(market)
   console.log("   marketHash added to MongoDB: " + market.marketHash);

   return res;
});

Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
    console.log("   All non-duplicate ActiveMarkets have been added to MongoDB.");
    console.log(promises)// why are no promises making it into this Promise All array????
    })
    .catch((e) => {
        console.log("   Error with Promise All: " + e);
    });
```

Comment: This is perfect! One typo I noticed is that "if (!exists)" should be "if (exists)" for my needs. But other than that, this snippet of code plugged and played in my application flawlessly. You're the man.

This is more helpful than you even realize. I didn't know MonogDB supported async/await so this will help me in other sections of my code! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your code, I'd say, the "problem" is with this: `dbo.collection("bettingmarkets").findOne()`.

This code is asynchronous. That means, it will likely run after you are done with the for-loop.

MongoDB is a bit ambiguous in its documentation about [db.collection.findOne()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/), but if it happens to match [this documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/mongodb/actions/collection.findOne/) you could use a Promise instead of callbacks.

In this case, you can use an `Array.prototype.map` to fill your array (similiar to antino's response).